# How to read Windows Service Default Timer value from app.config

Tags: .net-4.0, windows-services, timer

Please let me know how to read the `TimerFrequency` from the following app.config

```
<configSections>
<sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
    <section name="Project1WindowsService.MyService" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<applicationSettings>
    <Project1WindowsService.MyService>
        <setting name="TimerFrequency" serializeAs="String">
            <value>300000</value>
        </setting>
    </Project1WindowsService.MyService>
</applicationSettings>
```

Answer (score 1):

Properties.Settings.Default.TimerFrequency will give you back 300000

Edit:

Ok, got it to work but you'll have to perform a bit of surgery on your app.config. it should look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
<!--        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >-->
            <section name="Project1WindowsService.MyService" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
<!--        </sectionGroup>-->
    </configSections>

<!--    <applicationSettings>-->

      <Project1WindowsService.MyService>
            <setting name="TimeFrequency" serializeAs="String">
                <value>300000</value>
            </setting>
        </Project1WindowsService.MyService>

<!--    </applicationSettings>-->
</configuration>
```

and you can retrieve the value as follows:

```
ClientSettingsSection sec  = (ClientSettingsSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Project1WindowsService.MyService");

var element = sec.Settings.Get("TimeFrequency").Value.ValueXml.InnerText;
```

The value of element is 30000

Dont forget to add reference to System.Configuration.

Cheers

Comment: its not working for me.... note that I haven't using any resource settings file...